# How can I fix the Microsoft Visual Studio error: Register Visual Studio tool

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I installed Visual Studio 2022 Community and Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise. I cannot open the Register Visual Studio Tool. When I started Visual Studio with safe mode `devenv.exe /safemode` it generated an error shown by this attached image

[image]

The error appears in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise and Visual Studio 2022 Community

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks